# jQuery : displaying a message under several conditions with radio buttons

Tags: jquery, if-statement, radio-button, conditional-statements

What I'm trying to achieve:

when carRadio has no selection and nameRadio has a selection and transmissionRadio has a selection, display the message located in `<div class="formalertmsg">Please select a car.</div>`

Otherwise, hide it.

I wrote a function called checkCar which is IF transmissionRadio is checked AND 
carRadio is not checked, then display the message. Otherwise, the message is hidden.

I managed to write this function and it seems to work properly. I'm having troubles understanding why the message doesn't vanish after the user has selected an option on carRadio.

I added `carRadio.on("change", checkCar);` at the end of my code to trigger my checkCar function when the user makes a change on carRadio. But it doesn't work. I really don't understand why it is not hiding the message since checkCar if conditions are not met (transmissionRadio is checked and carRadio IS ALSO checked so the else statement should get triggered but it's not for some reason).

Also just so you since it's part of the code, when the user makes a change on nameRadio, if carRadio is checked, carRadio gets reset, while the transmissionRadio selection remains (if a radio button was selected).

Can someone please explain to me why `carRadio.on("change", checkCar);` is not behaving the way I would like? And help me correct this without rewriting all my code from scratch? Thank you, Kim.

Here's my code:

```js
var nameRadio = $(".radio-838 input") ;
var carRadio = $(".radio-839 input") ;
var transmissionRadio = $(".radio-60 input");


//Reset the Car selection when a change has been made on the Name
  function carInit() {
    carRadio.prop("checked", false);
  }
  nameRadio.on("change", carInit);

// Alert msg when no Car is selected and a Transmission is selected
  function checkCar (){
   if(transmissionRadio.is(":checked") && carRadio.not(":checked")){
    $(".formalertmsg").show();
   }
   else{
    $(".formalertmsg").hide();
   }
  }
  nameRadio.on("change", checkCar);
        carRadio.on("change", checkCar);
    

$(window).on('load', checkCar );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formel" id="formtde">
  <h3>Name</h3>
  <p>
  <span class="radio-838">
  <span class="first">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="JOHN">
    <span>JOHN</span>
      </label>
  </span>
  <span class="last">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-838" value="BOBBY">
    <span>BOBBY</span>
   </label>
  </span>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>

<div class="formel" id="formgec">
 <h3>Car</h3>
 <p>
 <span class="radio-839">
   <span class="first">
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="FORD">
     <span>FORD</span>
    </label>
   </span>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="CHEVROLET">
     <span>CHEVROLET</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="PORSCHE">
     <span>PORSCHE</span>
    </label>
    <label>
     <input type="radio" name="radio-839" value="NISSAN">
     <span>NISSAN</span>
    </label>
 </span>
 </p>
    <div class="formalertmsg">
Please select a car.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="formel">
  <h3>Transmission</h3>
  <p>
  <span class="radio-60">
  <span class="first">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-60" value="MANUAL">
    <span>MANUAL</span>
      </label>
  </span>
  <span class="last">
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-60" value="AUTO">
    <span>AUTO</span>
   </label>
  </span>
 </span>
 </p>
</div>
```